# In c# - Arrays in set and get method implement

Tags: c#, arrays

I am strugling with the `int[Array]` since yesterday. 
I have the following code:

```
public int[] Numbers
    {
        get
        {
            return class.intNumbers();
        }
        set
        {
            int[] Number = class.intNumbers();
             Number[Number.Length + 1] = value; 
            writer.NumberValue("Name", "Id", "Here goes the Array");
        }
    }
```

What I want the code to do is to take the array from other class and on the next index to put my value.(Fails at `Number[Number + 1] = value;`) The get method is succesfully finished, all I have to do now is "set". Do you have any ideas?

P.S I only want to use array and not arraylist :)

Comment: When you `set`, you are assigning the *entire array* - it looks like you're actually trying to *append*, though (you're trying to write one value after the end). Can you clarify? Note: arrays are very expensive to append to (because: you can't - you need to allocate a larger array and copy all the data over); are you sure you wouldn't prefer a `List<int>` ?

Comment: `return class.intNumbers();` - is this code compiled successfully?

Comment: @MongZhu I read that as essentially "append" - i.e. "put the new value at the next position" - which of course will fail with an array because it is out-of-range; it will also fail in C++ : but in a more subtle way (overwriting a random memory location without detecting the error)

Comment: An array is a fixed size collection, you cannot resize it with `Number[Number.Length + 1] = value`. That would be the next exception. Use a `List<int>`

Comment: Marc I changed the code (At the index). I dont want to use an arraylist because i was told not to. -JohnyL "Yes it does compile"

Comment: @prog.cpp I'd be next in line to tell you not to use `ArrayList` too! But perhaps the reasons are different... I'd say "use `List<int>` instead". So : what are you trying to do? Are you trying "append" here?

Comment: _" I dont want to use an arraylist because i was told not to"_ That was a good suggestion. But whoever suggested it didn't want you to use an `ArrayList`(obsolete) but i'm sure he was fine with a generic `List<int>`.

Comment: @MarcGravell that is an interesting interpretation, but I can follow the thought. Thanx for the hint

Comment: @MarcGravell I am new to Programing so i thought "List<int>" == "List<int>" . I will try to use that and reply to you later. :)

Comment: @prog.cpp if you mean "`List<int>` == `ArrayList`" - then : they certainly do similar things, but `ArrayList` is the .NET 1.1 pre-generics version where everything is `object`; `List<int>` is the generic version. It essentially wraps an array (although that is an implementation detail) providing convenient "append" etc (and is more efficient than constantly resizing an array, by keeping some spare capacity). So it all comes down to: for what *reason* are you trying to avoid `ArrayList`. If the intent is to learn to deal with naked arrays, then: fine - but frankly "appending" to a...

Comment: ... naked array on an element-by-element basis IMO illustrates a pretty large design error

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use ArrayResizer, although I don't know why you do not want to use List here.

   ```
   int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
   Array.Resize(ref arr , 5);
   ```

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx
2. You could also implement private `List<int> numberList`
   Then return `numberList.ToArray();` in getter.

Comment: I think moving to `List<int>` is indeed the right choice here, but I'd suggest that `ToArray()` is unnecessary and harmful here - that'll be allocation-heavy